# Set background color of the deletion control of a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In an iPhone/iPad app, I'm using a UITableView to display a list of items that can be edited.  I can successfully alternate the background color of the rows in my table view.  However, when I turn on "editing mode" (i.e., display the deletion control), each cell appears to be shifted to the right, and the deletion control slides in from the left.

My problem is that the deletion control has a white background color.  I'd like the background color of the deletion control to match the background color of my UITableViewCell.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I realize not enough time has passed since asking the question for you to answer your own question, but better than editing @PengOne's answer to include the real answer is to wait the eight hours (or get 100 rep :) so you can answer and accept..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One answer is to, in the getCellContentView function, where you create frames/labels and add them as subviews, add an additional label that is much wider and starts with a negative X value.  Then, this can be colored.  Since it's drawn "underneath" the deletion control, the color shows through.

The trick is to understanding that the deletion control isn't drawing "white" anywhere.  The deletion control itself's background color is *already* clear, so you have to fit something underneath.  Negative "x" value does the trick.

Comment: This worked for me. Create a label that is much wider thant the cell and add the correct background color to that label with no text. That label will show through through the deletion control.

Comment: Works perfect. Also on the left side when the "Delete" text occurs!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the background of the `accessoryView` which houses the delete button to `UIColor clearColor`. I'm not sure the exact syntax, but something like:

```
[tableView.editingAccessoryView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

If that doesn't do it for you, you may try setting the background of the entire tableview to clear. This should not affect your customized colors for each cell.

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting the accessoryView backgroundColor to clearColor, but that doesn't work (doesn't have any effect).  However, setting the tableView backgroundColor to clearColor DOES have an effect (but it's not the desired effect).  Setting the tableView backgroundColor to clearColor effectively makes the entire tableView "black" (completely see-through) except where elements are drawn.

Comment: @Matt, did you set the `editingAccessoryView` background or just the `accessoryView` background? These are two different views.