# ios 6 UITableViewCell delete button has background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have custom UITableViewCell with background pattern

using this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(homeCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
}
```

and the result was good,

ImageLink: [link](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8606/iossimulatorscreenshotm.png)

but when i swipe to delete, the delete button comes with background color overriding the content of the cell

### ImageLink: [link](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/3673/iossimulatorscreenshotml.png)

i followed some solutions that i found here in stackoverflow, but none solved my problem

i've tried clearing background color of the delete button using this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(homeCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // create uiview
    UIView* myBackgroundView            = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    myBackgroundView.backgroundColor    = [UIColor clearColor];

    // assign the uiview
    cell.editingAccessoryView   = myBackgroundView;
    cell.backgroundView         = myBackgroundView;

    // my background patter
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellBG.png"]];
}
```

but the result was not good, the whole cell background was with no background color

ImageLink: [link](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/8606/iossimulatorscreenshotm.png)

how to display delete button with no background color? please help

---

some of the solutions i tried:
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696136/swipe-to-delete-in-uitableviewcell-has-white-background-need-clear)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208018/set-background-color-of-the-deletion-control-of-a-uitableviewcell)

[link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791437/maintain-uitableviewcell-background-color-when-going-into-edit-mode)

Comment: Are you adding custom labels or are you using the default labels? The delete button doesn't have a background color. It more looks like the two labels are being resized when the delete button appears.

Comment: yes, i'm using custom labels 
3 labels, one is big at the top
and 2 label at the bottom 

how can i fix this?
thank you @Lukas

Comment: You should always add your custom subviews to the cell's contentView.

Comment: @phix23 i added my custom labels using interface builder, what should i do in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not from the delete button background, the problem is that when the delete button is shown, your UITableViewCell content view size is decreased. By adding the labels from IB they are added to the contentView.

What I did in my other projects (I didn't use autolayout) I set the springs and struts so that the labels size will be re sized when the UITableView cell will be re sized.

Comment: thank you @danypata 
you showed me the real problem,

i googled and found out that the problem is about constraints:


 the constraints added by interface builder was between my customView and UiTableViewCell and it should be between my customView and cell.contentView.

i found great solution in this link: [UITableViewCell Editing with Autolayout](http://www.lextech.com/uitableviewcell-editing-with-autolayout)

Comment: thanks for this answer! It helped fix a bug for an app that has to suppport iOS 6.x even now.